# Unable to convert String to JSON for google charts

Tags: json, google-visualization

Can any body explain me how to parse the below code in JSON. When I remove `{type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}` and `\"huu\"`, I am able to generate the chart

Code Snippet :

```
var obj=JSON.parse("[[\"Carrier Name\",{type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}, \"Transactions\", \"Spending\", \"Chargeable Weight\"], [\" - AK - AirAsia Berhad dba AirAsia\",\"huu\", 15, 0.8778833367217757, 0.9236859587487404]]");

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

`{type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}` is a syntax error from JSON perspective. You should  change that part to `{"type": "string", "role": "tooltip"}`. I did not face any problems with `"huu"` when I validated the JSON string using [JSOnLint](http://jsonlint.com/). JSONLint may not work on recent FF. Use chrome.